# Distinct SUM in recursive tablix

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to report the sum of sales by user and include recursive totals. The problem is, each account has 2 account managers, and the account managers can come from different teams. At each parent level, I want return the distinct sum of each relevant account at the group level.

For example:

```
Name          LEVEL       AccountNum        Sales
James         1           A1                1000
                          A2                2000
                          A3                5000
Mike          2           A1                1000
                          A2                2000
Sally         3           A1                1000
John          3           A1                1000
Mary          3           A2                2000
Matt          2           A2                2000
                          A3                5000  
Andy          3           A2                2000
                          A3                5000
 Bob          3           A3                5000
```

I want to return the totals only and not show the account details:

```
Name            Sales
James           8000
Mike            3000
Sally           1000
John            1000
Mary            2000 
Matt            7000
Andy            7000
Bob             5000
```

I'm a relative newbie to SSRS, so would massively appreciate any advice on how to achieve the above group totals! Thanks!

I tried using recursive queries in SQL, but the totals only work up to Level 2, because of the cross-team accounts.  Using partition by ranking also only works up to Level 2. (e.g. 
`{row_number() over (partition by AccountNum, TeamLeaderKey ORDER BY AccountNum ASC))}`) in order to exclude any with rank > 1.  This falls down at level 1 when there are account with account managers from different teams at level 2.

Comment: Apologies for the bad formatting - newbie to the forum as well!

Comment: Format it as code; edit your q, highlight the lines and click the `{}` button above the textbox

Comment: Include the sql you've tried that didn't work. It might save someone some typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else ever comes across this problem, this is how I solved it. I introduced two new fields in my dataset:
IntraTeamRank:

```
Case When ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNum, TeamLeaderKey ORDER BY AccountNum ASC) > 1 Then 0 Else 1 End
```

InterTeamRank:

```
Case When ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNum ORDER BY AccountNum ASC) > 1 Then 0 Else 1 End
```

I have a parameter set up in SSRS to return the max level.

I then used the following expression in SSRS:

```
IIf( Level() < (Parameters!MaxLevel.Value - 1),
  SUM((Fields!InterTeamRank.Value * Fields!Amount.Value), "StaffName", Recursive),
IIf( Level() = (Parameters!MaxLevel.Value - 1),
  SUM((Fields!IntraTeamRank.Value * Fields!Amount.Value), "StaffName", Recursive),
  SUM(Fields!Amount.Value), "StaffName")
)
)
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it worked for my purposes.  It would break if an account were shared between regions, as opposed to just teams, but it is unlikely in my scenario. I'd still be interested to know if anyone has a more robust solution.